# Impressão formatada que substitui o uso de .format() em versões do python da 3.6 em diante. Como utilizar?

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatação

Sabemos que:

```
"{0}:{1}:{2}".format(hora,minuto, segundo)
```

é equivalente a:

```
f"{hora}:{minuto}:{segundo}"
```

Qual o equivalente da expressão abaixo utilizando a notação f" " ?

```
print("{0:3},{1:5}".format(12,54))
```

Fiz várias tentativas mas não deu certo. É possível substituir qualquer ".fornmat()" pela notação f" " ?

E se fosse uma impressão com ponto flutuante e precisasse especificar a precisão? Como seria com a notação f" "?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As f-strings na verdade usam *exatamente* as mesmas marcações de formatação que o método `.format` - 
No `.format` os marcadores `:` ou `!` indicam o início da marcação de formatação - e o que vai antes desses sinais pode estar em branco, ser a posição ou o nome do argumento no format. No exemplo que você coloca, por exemplo:

`print("{0:3},{1:5}".format(12,54))` indica que  o primeiro número vai usar 3 espaços, alinhado a direita, e o segundo número 5 espaços, alinhado a esquerda.

É um exemplo bastante ruim, mas o equivalente a isso com f-strings é simplesmente `f"{12:3}, {54:5}"`.

Se esses valores estivessem em variáveis, isso fica mais visível:

```
hora = 12
minutos = 54
# com format:
print("{0:3}:{1:54}".format(hora, minutos))

# com f-strings:
print(f"{hora:3}:{minutos:5}")
```

Da mesma forma, todas as marcações para formatação de números em ponto flutuante, alinhamento, preenchimento de outros caracteres que funcionam com o `.format` funcionam exatamente da mesma forma com f-strings:

`f"Preço com juros: R${123.55 * 1.13:.02f}"` - limita o número a cada duas casas decimais.

Tanto é que não existe uma documentação separada para a formatação de f-strings, por que deve ser usada a mesma documentação existente para o o método `.format`: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/

Além dos especificadores ":" e "!" para iniciar a formatação, a partir do Pthon 3.8, as f-strings também suportam o sinal "=" para ajudar a depuração - além do valor, o sinal "=" imprime também a expressão entre as chaves:

```
In [108]: hora = 12                                                                                                                  

In [109]: print(f"{hora=}")                                                                                                          
hora=12
```